# How to calculate what the sum of these Strings is?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys
import random
Num1 = str(random.randint(1,109))
Num2 = str(random.randint(1,109))
Opp = ["+", "-", "*", "^", "/"]

secure_random = random.SystemRandom()

Operator = secure_random.choice(Opp)
if Operator == "^":
    Num2 = "2"
print ("som:", Num1 , Operator , Num2, "= ")
```

I created some variables, one of which is an operator, I printed but now I have to calculate it...
I tried using `eval()`, but I could not get this to work.

How would I calculate this sum?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can indeed use `eval`, although in general you want to avoid using it if possible, as there is no safety check on what string expressions are executed.

Your exercise is `s = Num1+Operator+Num2`. You can do `eval(s)` either by intermediate declaration of the string `s`, or by typing its right-hand-side into the eval..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use stack like functionality in Python to create your own calculator. Below is a simple example of a calculator which calculates:

- sum,
- difference,
- multiplication
- exponentiation
- division

It can calculate expressions like these ones:

```
"1 - 2 * 3 + 4 * 2 - 1 - 2"
"8 / 2 + 1 / 2 * 2 / 2 - 1"
```

Spaces are used to separate the tokens in this simple implementation. More tests are available below in the source code:

```
def calc(str):
    tokens = str.split(" ")
    vals = []
    ops = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(tokens):
        t = tokens[i]
        if t == "+":
            processPlus(ops, vals)
        elif t == "*":
            ops.append(t)
        elif t == "-":
            processPlus(ops, vals)
            i, t = incrementAndGet(i, t, tokens)
            vals.append(float(t) * -1)
        elif t == "^":
            previousVal = vals.pop()
            i, t = incrementAndGet(i, t, tokens)
            vals.append(pow(previousVal, float(t)))
        elif t == "/":
            previousVal = vals.pop()
            i, t = incrementAndGet(i, t, tokens)
            vals.append(previousVal / float(t))
        else:
            vals.append(float(t))
        i += 1
    while len(ops) > 0:
        processOp(vals, ops)
    return sum(vals)


def incrementAndGet(i, t, tokens):
    i += 1
    t = tokens[i]
    return i, t


def processPlus(ops, vals):
    if len(ops) > 0:
        processOp(vals, ops)
    ops.append("+")


def processOp(vals, ops):
    op = ops.pop()
    if op == "+":
        vals.append(vals.pop() + vals.pop())
    elif op == "*":
        vals.append(vals.pop() * vals.pop())

# Test section
def check(expr, expected):
    res = calc(expr)
    print(res)
    assert res == expected


check("8 / 2 / 2 / 2", 1.0)
check("8 / 2 + 1 / 2 / 2", 4.25)
check("8 / 2 + 1 / 2 * 2 / 2", 4.5)
check("8 / 2 + 1 / 2 * 2 / 2 - 1", 3.5)
check("1 + 2", 3)
check("1 - 2", -1)
check("2 * 3", 6)
check("1 + 2 * 2", 5)
check("2 * 3 + 2", 8)
check("1 * 2 + 2 * 3", 8)
check("1 * 2 + 2 * 3 + 1", 9)
check("1 * 2 + 2 * 3 + 1 + 2", 11)
check("1 * 2 + 2 * 3 + 1 + 2 * 2", 13)
check("1 - 2 * 3 + 4 * 2 - 1 - 2", 0.0)
check("1 - 2 * 3 + 4 * 2 - 1 - 2 * 2", -2.0)
check("1 - 2 * 3 + 4 * 2 - 1 - 2 * 2 - 3", -5.0)
check("2 ^ 2", 4.0)
check("2 + 3 ^ 2", 11.0)
check("2 + 3 ^ 2 - 1", 10.0)
check("2 + 3 ^ 2 - 1 * 3", 8.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` does not support operator `^`, but you could get around with it.

```
import sys
import random
Num1 = str(random.randint(1,109))
Num2 = str(random.randint(1,109))
Opp = ["+", "-", "*", "^", "/"]

secure_random = random.SystemRandom()

Operator = secure_random.choice(Opp)
if Operator == "^":
    Operator = "*"
    Num2 = Num1
result = eval(Num1+Operator+Num2)
print ("som:", Num1 , Operator , Num2, "= ", result)
```